# django unable to pass request to form while using formset. Produces `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
#forms.py
class RequestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(RequestModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BusinessForm(RequestModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Business
    fields = ('title', 'stitle', 'gstin', 'address')

    def clean_gstin(self):
        user = self.request.user
        gstin = self.cleaned_data['gstin'].upper()
        if Business.objects.filter(owner=user, gstin=gstin).exists():
            raise  ValidationError("A Business with that GSTIN already exists")
        return gstin
```

---

```
#views.py
class BaseFormView(FormView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BaseFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super(BaseFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BusinessCreateView(BaseFormView):
    BusinessFormSet = formset_factory(BusinessForm, extra=3)
    form_class = BusinessFormSet
    success_url = '/dashboard'
    template_name = "business/business_create_form.html"
```

Everything works well if I set `extra=1` for the `formset_factory`. But when `extra = 2` or something greater than 1, the error is thrown: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'`

I have identified the problem here. Since I'm popping `request` inside the `__init__` function of `RequestModelForm`(which is called multiple times when extra is set to more than 1). And there is no `request` since it is already been popped.

I tried doing `self.request = kwargs.get("request")` instead of `self.request = kwargs.pop("request")`. But this throws another error 
    `'BusinessForm' object has no attribute 'request'`.

How to overcome this? Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass the extra kwarg `request` to the form, but the `BusinessFormSet` needs to have this information explicitly. Overwriting the `get_form_kwargs` method in the FormView doesn't work in the way you've described because it'll pass all these as kwargs to what you have defined as `form_class`.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms

For example probably what would work is:

```
class BaseFormView(FormView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['form_kwargs'] = {'request': self.request}
        return kwargs
    ...
```